# .NET 6 Azure functions using .NET Core 3.1 libraries

Tags: .net, azure, azure-functions, .net-6.0

Is it currently possible to get an Azure build running for a .NET 6 Azure Function that has to use .NET Core 3.1 Nugets.  I spent ages today with no luck tweaking the YAML files and adding reference.  The problems that occured were messages about missmatcking libraries that were only used by the Nugets.  Once those were added the publish failed with.

"Dotnet command failed with non-zero exit code..."

Changing to .NET Core 3.1 works just fine though.

Comment: See https://codetraveler.io/2021/05/28/creating-azure-functions-using-net-5/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Microsoft Community doc](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/apps-on-azure/net-on-azure-functions-roadmap/ba-p/2197916?WT.mc_id=dotnet-13135-bramin)

> .NET 6 functions will support both in-process and isolated process options. The in-process option will support the full feature set available in .NET Core 3.1 functions today, including Durable Functions and rich binding types. The isolated process option will provide an upgrade path for apps using this option for **.NET 5** and initially will have the same feature set and limitations.
>
> And .NET 6 LTS reaches general availability in November 2021, Then you’ll be able to deploy and run .NET 6 Azure Functions.